# TypeScript: "Overload signature is not compatible with function implementation" in class method overload

Tags: typescript

The TypeScript compiler complains with `"This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature."` for any of the following overloads:

```js
export class FullId {
  // other stuff

  static parse(toParse: string): FullId;
  static parse(toParse: string, withIdType: 'U' | 'S' | 'O' | 'T'): FullId;
  static parse(
    toParse: string,
    withIdType: 'U' | 'S' | 'O' | 'T' | undefined,
    withEntityType: string | undefined
  ): FullId;

  static parse(
    toParse: string,
    withIdType: 'U' | 'S' | 'O' | 'T' | undefined,
    withEntityType: string | undefined
  ): FullId {
    // my implementation
   }
}
```

It's basically a method which can be called with one, two, or three arguments.
I don't really understand what the problem is: I've created overloads distinct from the implementation, and in the implementation any but the first argument is optional. Removing the `static` modifier doesn't change anything as far as I can tell.

Comment: You should make second and third arguments in the implementation signature optional with question mark syntax: `withIdType?: ..., withEntityType?: ...`. TS doesn't treat optional argument in the same way as argument accepting `undefined` here for some reason

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! If you provide an answer, I'll gladly accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the arguments optional using the question mark syntax

```
export class FullId {
  static parse(toParse: string): FullId;
  static parse(toParse: string, withIdType: 'U' | 'S' | 'O' | 'T'): FullId;
  static parse(
    toParse: string,
    withIdType: 'U' | 'S' | 'O' | 'T' | undefined,
    withEntityType: string | undefined
  ): FullId;

  static parse(
    toParse: string,
    withIdType?: 'U' | 'S' | 'O' | 'T',
    withEntityType?: string
  ): FullId {
    // ...
  }
}
```

For some reason TS doesn't treat optional argument and argument accepting `undefined` in the same way here

Comment: Typescript never treats optional arguments and arguments that accept undefined as the same. Optional arguments can be excluded altogether, but arguments that take undefined must expressly be passed `undefined`.